# Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack.Text

Tags: c#-4.0, servicestack

This is a runtime error I'm getting from a console app that references ServiceStack.Text. I have manually deleted the nuget package and reinstalled it using the package manager console. The target framework is .Net Framework 4, not Client Profile.
thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you add the runtime error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be unrelated to ServiceStack.text. It was related to some conflicting references.